# Qlikview interpreting results as string instead of field name

Tags: qlikview

I have a problem where I have a series of **Milestones** and I am basically trying to load the date of the next milestone. This is all for order tracking and forecasting. The table I am pulling from already has a current status of the milestone that just occurred so I am pulling that successfully. But when I try to add this number to a series of strings to reconstruct the field I need to load, it is only getting the literal value.

For example, if the current order status is **MS_05**, the script should be pulling up **MS_06** for the next date.

**Script:**

[image: Scripts]

**Result:**

[image: Result]

I have tried using **chr(91) & chr(93)** for brackets and replacing single quotes with **chr(39)** and a multitude of other options. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is just substituted with the current literal value in the script - it doesn't know it's a string or number or field name or anything. This gives good flexibility in how variables are used but does cause confusion. The good thing is it should be simple to fix - just wrap your variable in single quotes - `'$(variableName)'` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Sort of! No matter what I did, Qlikview would not recognize the string as a field name so I just extracted the integer of the milestone and then used it as a pick formula on a preceding load. It worked great!

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rftGn.png)